# Ide Netbeans в Линукс C++ подчеркивает красным некоторые функции из stl не смотря на то что заголовки подключены

Tags: netbeans

> **ВОПРОС НЕ В КОДЕ, ВОПРОС В ОПИСАНИИ!**

У меня Ide Netbeans  линукс подчеркивает красным буд-то находит ошибку некоторые функции из stl, к примеру **std::function<>** и **std::make_shared<>**.
Причем все заголовки подключены и код компилируется верно.

Подскажите если знаете, как можно это исправить? К примеру в приведенном тестовом коде - подчеркиваются обращения к указателям и создание указателей

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<string>

class A {
private:
    std::string s;
public:

    A(std::string _s) : s(_s) {
        std::cout << "A -> Init\n";
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "A -> Deinit\n";
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
};

class Base {
public:

    virtual ~Base() {
    };
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
public:

    Derived(std::shared_ptr<A> _a) : a(_a) {
        std::cout << "Derived -> Init\n";
    }

    ~Derived() {
        std::cout << "Derived -> Deinit\n";
    }

    void method() override {
        a->print();
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
};

class User {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Base> lp;
public:

    User(std::shared_ptr<Base> _lp) : lp(_lp) {
        std::cout << "User -> Init\n";
    };

    ~User() {
        std::cout << "User -> Deinit\n";
    }

    void do_test() {
        lp->method();
    }
};

User f() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>("MY String");
    std::cout << "########################\n";
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::cout << "########################\n";

    std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::make_shared<Derived>(a);

    User u(p);
    return u;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << "==================\n";
    User usr = f();
    std::cout << "==================\n";

    std::cout << "########################\n";
    usr.do_test();
    std::cout << "########################\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а при сборке все работает?

Comment: и собирается и исполняется корректно. Правда я через самописный cmake собираю, но сборку из ide запускаю.

Comment: если ты собираешь через cmake, тогда зачем тебе эта программа, скачать visual code или st3

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин удобная и хорошо подсвечивает синтакс (ну кроме описанных случаев). По сути для этого и нужен ide.

Comment: visual code МЕГА удобный, подсвечивает код, плагины, багов почти нет(да, почти)

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин Не понравился он мне.

Comment: мда уж, нетбианс "гораздо круче"...

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин Да уж покруче новороченного блокнота будет) Если со студией сравнивать - то он поближе будет

Comment: мне он чисто из-за недодизайна не нравится

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин не знаю можно ли черным его сделать но по функциональности он круче. А редактор лучше по начинке выбирать)

Comment: какой функционал там есть какого нет в VC?

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин Как минимум - нормальный и удобный дебагинг. Если Вам очень нравится VC - то Вы к сожалению не сможете мне помочь с моей проблемой, посему предлагаю нам на этом прекратить возникший холивар.

Comment: нужен дебаг? тогда Qt Creator

Comment: Я не прошу предлагать альтернатив, я просил лишь помощь с Netbeans.

Comment: ну-ну QtCreator в милиарды раз лучше